# Spanning sets and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{3}$, find $S$ such that ${\rm Span}(S)=V$ and such that $S$ is linearly dependent.

For this question I have no idea where to start, how would I even think of such an $S$? I would prefer an explanation towards the solution rather than just the answer to this one. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know any other examples of spanning sets? (E.g. for $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$.)

Comment: I know the definition of a spanning set but I haven't been introduced to any specific spanning sets.

Comment: Notice that if you already have a set that spans, then a larger set still spans. You can put so many elements that you could even consider all of $V$ as the spanning set. More economically, since the $0$ is never in a linearly independent set, you could drop the $0$ into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
One set that spans $\mathbf{R}^3$ is the set made out of the unit vectors $\hat \imath,\hat\jmath$ and $\hat k$, which is $$\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\},$$ since every element $(x,y,z)$ of $\mathbf{R}^3$ can be written as a linear combination using those vectors : $$(x,y,z)=x\hat\imath+y\hat \jmath+z\hat k=x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1).$$ Now use the fact that if some vector in a list of vectors in $V$ is a linear combination of other vectors in that same list, then the list is linearly dependent.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but surely your choice of $S$ is not linearly dependent.

Comment: @user2850514 Yes, the set I presented isn't linearly dependent. But if you use the fact I mentioned in the last statements then you can make it linearly dependent.

Comment: I understand we can write any $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ using the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ however I don't necessarily understand how your final point relates to the problem.

Comment: @user2850514 I gave you a list of linearly independent vectors, use my final point to find some suitable vector(s) to add to that list such that the list becomes linearly dependent.

Comment: Ok, so if we consider the set $S=\{(1,2,3),(2,4,6),(3,6,9)\}$ this is linearly dependent but how do I know that ${\rm Span}(S)=V$?

Comment: @user2850514 You didn't follow my hint, not every linearly dependent list of vectors spans $V$. In fact, considering the set $S$ you gave we have that $\operatorname{span}(S)=\{(x,2x,3x)\colon x\in\mathbf{R}\}\neq V$. Now back to my hint : $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ already spans $V$, so if you add some vectors in it it will still span $V$. Now to make it linearly dependent all you have to do is to add a vector that's a linear combination of $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for
the three  triplets
$\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)$,  $\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$ and
$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)
$,
you have for an arbitrary one like $\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right)$
its expression as a linear combination:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right)
=
a
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)
+
b\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)
+
c\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)
$$